# Use AdditionalFields to compare to field in a different class

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, remote-validation

**Introduction**

In MVC Core I have a base ViewModel and two ViewModels included in the base model as properties, like so:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public FirstViewModel First { get; set; }    
    public SecondViewModel Second { get; set; }
}
```

In `FirstViewModel` I added a custom validation attribute on one of the properties, inheriting from `RemoteAttribute`. My goal is to use this attribute comparing the value to a property in `SecondViewModel`. I've set this up using the `AdditionalFields` property of the `RemoteAttribute`.

I think my problem lies in the way the HTML attributes are added to the control in the razor view:

```
data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.PropOfModelFirst,*.PropOfModelSecond"
```

When the clientside validation is calling the controller action, the ***.** is replaced by the framework by **First.**, which is wrong, because the second value is not part of the **First**-class.

I tried prepending the classname to the second property, resulting in

```
data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.PropOfModelFirst,*.Second.PropOfModelSecond"
```

but as can be expected this is changed to First.Second.PropOfModelSecond.

**Question**

Can the AdditionalFields property be used to compare against values from another ViewModel?

Comment: Short answer is no. But you are using view models, so why not just have a  single 'flat' view model containing all properties?

Comment: My viewmodels have quite a lot of properties and they separate the fields into different functional categories, but changing them into a single model is worth considering.
Is there also a longer 'yes' answer? :)

Comment: Using the `[Remote]` attrbute, then only if you were to modify the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive,js` (that would be crazy). But the `[Remote]` attribute is not very efficient anyway - once its initially validated, then it is then validated on every `.keyup()` (i.e. can potentially make a lot of ajax calls. You can always write you own `ajax()` code to make the call to your method (and if its not valid, update the element generated by your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Feel free to put them in an answer and I'll accept it when no valid alternatives are suggested.

Comment: Sure, but about to eat, so it will be an hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `AdditionalFields` to compare against values from another ViewModel. The reason is that the rules are added to `jquery.validate.js` by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin (which reads the `data-val-*` attributes generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods). Specifically it is the `adapters.add("remote", ["url", "type", "additionalfields"], function (options) {`  method that is pre-pending `First` to the property names.

One option would be to use a single 'flat' view model containing all properties.

If that is not desirable, then you can just write your own ajax code to call your server method that performs the validation. This actually has some added performance benefits as well. By default, after initial validation triggered by the `.blur()` event, validation is performed on every `.keyup()` event, meaning that you are potentially making a lot of ajax and database calls if the user initially entered an invalid value.

Remove the `[Remote]` attribute, and add the following script (I'll assume the properties are `First.ABC` and `Second.XYZ`)

```
$('#First_ABC').change(function() {
    var url = '@Url.Action(...)'; // add your action name
    var input = $(this);
    var message = $('[data-valmsg-for="First.ABC"]'); // or give the element and id attribute
    $.post(url, { abc: input.val(), xyz: $('#Second_XYZ').val() }, function(response) {
        var isValid = response === true || response === "true";
        if (isValid) {
            input.addClass('valid').removeClass('input-validation-error');
            message.empty().addClass('field-validation-valid').removeClass('field-validation-error');
        } else {
            input.addClass('input-validation-error').removeClass('valid');
            message.text(response).addClass('field-validation-error').removeClass('field-validation-valid');
        }
    })
});
```

where the controller method would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validate(string abc, string xyz)
{
    bool isValid = .... // code to validate
    if (isValid)
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json("your error message", JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet)
    }
}
```